# Query in Linked Mysql server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

Hi i have linked my MYSQL server (172.xx.xx.xx) to my sql server . but while useing the query its providing the error.

```
select * from OPENQUERY ([MYSQL],'select * from example.address_table limit 10')
```

this query is working fine but while executing the below query its through the error:-

```
select * from OPENQUERY ([MYSQL],'select * from example.address_table
where (create_date between '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and '2015-01-31 23:59:59') or 
(modified_date between '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and '2015-01-31 23:59:59');
```

how to solve the query in linked server.

this is the error

> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')

Comment: You forgot to post the error! Please add it to your post.

Comment: *"Please add it to your post."* I've done this for you, but make sure you edit your post when you need to add important information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As given your error this should be the fix

```
select * from OPENQUERY ([MYSQL],'select * from example.address_table 
where (create_date between ''2015-01-01 00:00:00'' and ''2015-01-31 23:59:59'') or 
(modified_date between ''2015-01-01 00:00:00'' and ''2015-01-31 23:59:59'')');
```